# How to add timedelta for time in csv file using

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with date, time and one input. Then I need to first read some special time which is having same value. Then I want to add to that one hour one hour as a timedelta till to range of 6hours.

So here only 5 change. only change values with 5, I just need to separate the time which is related to the 5 values and then add timedelta (hours=1*6) into that each time
This is not write as a another column of data csv file.

```
data['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                        format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
t = data.loc[data['date_time'] == 5]
for it in range(6):
   time=[]
   time= t+timedelta(hours=1*it)
```

But it gave me an error.

Here what I expected output:

first separate the specific time of values 5

```html
date     time     x3                                           first expected time
10/3/2018 6:15:00  7
10/3/2018 6:45:00  5     first seperate the time related to        6:45:00 =1st time of 5
10/3/2018 7:45:00         7          the 5 
10/3/2018 9:00:00  7
10/3/2018 9:25:00  7
10/3/2018 9:30:00  5                                               9:30:00 = 2nd time of 5
10/3/2018 11:00:00 7
10/3/2018 11:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5                                              13:50:00 = 3rd time 0f 5
10/3/2018 15:00:00 7
10/3/2018 15:25:00 7
```

After separating add timedelta each of that time separately

final expected output:

```html
time                final output
6:45:00           6:45:00 +timedelta(hours=1*6)
09:30:00          9:30:00 +timedelta(hours=1*6)
13:50:00         13:50:00 +timedelta(hours=1*6)
```

Then for 7 value:

```html
date        time x3          first seperate time of 7
10/3/2018 6:15:00  7          6:15:00
10/3/2018 6:45:00  5
10/3/2018 7:45:00  7          7:45:00
10/3/2018 9:00:00  7          9:00:00
10/3/2018 9:25:00  7          9:25:00
10/3/2018 9:30:00         5
10/3/2018 11:00:00 7          11:00:00
10/3/2018 11:30:00 7          11:30:00
10/3/2018 13:30:00 7          13:30:00
```

Then add timedelta into that time separately:

```html
6:15:00             6:15:00 +timedelta(hours=1*2)
7:45:00             7:45:00 +timedelta(hours=1*2)
9:00:00             9:00:00 +timedelta(hours=1*2)
```

This timedelta I want to write in for loop

Subset of my csv file:

```html
date time x3
10/3/2018 6:15:00  7
10/3/2018 6:45:00  5
10/3/2018 7:45:00         7
10/3/2018 9:00:00    7
10/3/2018 9:25:00         7
10/3/2018 9:30:00         5
10/3/2018 11:00:00 7
10/3/2018 11:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5
10/3/2018 15:00:00 7
10/3/2018 15:25:00 7
10/3/2018 16:25:00 7
10/3/2018 18:00:00 5
10/3/2018 19:00:00 7
10/3/2018 19:30:00 7
10/3/2018 20:00:00 7
10/3/2018 22:05:00 7
```

My csv file :
[Csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

```html
For the reference to jezrael:

Here I want get the new value of 5 with the help of one summation equation in the range of timedelta (6 hours) from starting time for each value of 5.


Assume My new input take as X

Then 
I will take start time first as t of value of 5

Then 
x=[]
x3 = data['X3']
for _ in range (x3):
  if x3.all()==5:
    for i in range(t+timedelta(hours=1*it)for it in range(1,6)):
        X1 = 5 - 0.006 *np.sum(i*5)
        x.append(X1)

So each one houe one hour x values are there till to range 6.

For this I required the time and adding timedelta into it inside the for loop
```

For the refernce:

```html
here just want to use my csv file only read the start time and the value only. Then starting from time add one hour one hour into it to get the new value for x. 

take the first 5 value and the time.
my start time =t

X value 

start time      x
0               5
1 hr            4.97
2 hr            4.94
3 hr            4.91
4 hr            4.88
5 hr            4.85
6 hr            4.82

If in between two value of 5 time range < range of 6 hr

Then add 
5 value into 5 hr value then new value 
start time     x
0 hr          5+4.85
1hr           9.82

If in between two value of 5 time range > range of 6 hr

start time      x
0               5
1 hr            4.97
2 hr            4.94
3 hr            4.91
4 hr            4.88
5 hr            4.85
6 hr            4.82

Normally run this code.

So this should be continue.
```

Comment: What is final output in numbers? Only changed values with 5 ?

Comment: yes only change values with 5, I just need to separate the time which is related to the 5 values and then add timedelta (hours=1*6) into that each time.

Comment: Can you add final output also with anoter datetiems with 7 ?

Comment: @jezrael sure I will add, then I add my csv file also

Comment: OK, I think now I understand it ;) Only create solution ;)

Comment: @jezrael I added final output for 7 value also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
data['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                        format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = data['x3'].eq(5)

data['duration'] = data['date_time'].mask(mask, data['date_time'].dt.floor('d'))

m = mask.cumsum()
mask1 = (m != 0) & ~mask
td = pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(mask1.sum()) % 5 + 1, unit='h')
data['hours'] = (pd.Series(td, index=data.index[mask1])
                   .reindex(data.index, fill_value=pd.Timedelta(0)))

data['new'] =  data['hours'].dt.total_seconds() / 3600

data['new1'] =  5 - 0.006 *data['new']
print (data)
```

---

```
print (data)
         date      time  x3           date_time            duration    hours  \
0   10/3/2018   6:15:00   7 2018-03-10 06:15:00 2018-03-10 06:15:00 00:00:00   
1   10/3/2018   6:45:00   5 2018-03-10 06:45:00 2018-03-10 00:00:00 00:00:00   
2   10/3/2018   7:45:00   7 2018-03-10 07:45:00 2018-03-10 07:45:00 01:00:00   
3   10/3/2018   9:00:00   7 2018-03-10 09:00:00 2018-03-10 09:00:00 02:00:00   
4   10/3/2018   9:25:00   7 2018-03-10 09:25:00 2018-03-10 09:25:00 03:00:00   
5   10/3/2018   9:30:00   5 2018-03-10 09:30:00 2018-03-10 00:00:00 00:00:00   
6   10/3/2018  11:00:00   7 2018-03-10 11:00:00 2018-03-10 11:00:00 04:00:00   
7   10/3/2018  11:30:00   7 2018-03-10 11:30:00 2018-03-10 11:30:00 05:00:00   
8   10/3/2018  13:30:00   7 2018-03-10 13:30:00 2018-03-10 13:30:00 01:00:00   
9   10/3/2018  13:50:00   5 2018-03-10 13:50:00 2018-03-10 00:00:00 00:00:00   
10  10/3/2018  15:00:00   7 2018-03-10 15:00:00 2018-03-10 15:00:00 02:00:00   
11  10/3/2018  15:25:00   7 2018-03-10 15:25:00 2018-03-10 15:25:00 03:00:00   
12  10/3/2018  16:25:00   7 2018-03-10 16:25:00 2018-03-10 16:25:00 04:00:00   
13  10/3/2018  18:00:00   5 2018-03-10 18:00:00 2018-03-10 00:00:00 00:00:00   
14  10/3/2018  19:00:00   7 2018-03-10 19:00:00 2018-03-10 19:00:00 05:00:00   
15  10/3/2018  19:30:00   7 2018-03-10 19:30:00 2018-03-10 19:30:00 01:00:00   
16  10/3/2018  20:00:00   7 2018-03-10 20:00:00 2018-03-10 20:00:00 02:00:00   
17  10/3/2018  22:05:00   7 2018-03-10 22:05:00 2018-03-10 22:05:00 03:00:00   

    new   new1  
0   0.0  5.000  
1   0.0  5.000  
2   1.0  4.994  
3   2.0  4.988  
4   3.0  4.982  
5   0.0  5.000  
6   4.0  4.976  
7   5.0  4.970  
8   1.0  4.994  
9   0.0  5.000  
10  2.0  4.988  
11  3.0  4.982  
12  4.0  4.976  
13  0.0  5.000  
14  5.0  4.970  
15  1.0  4.994  
16  2.0  4.988  
17  3.0  4.982
```

Comment: Thank you friend for helping me. I am appreciating your effort to solve this problem  your answer is correct as far. But here I don't need a another column of hours in my csv file. first need to separate the time in values of 5. Then I need to write this adding timedelta inside of for loop. it is okay that not adding this hours as a column. if it is like that how to write that code inside of the for loop?

Comment: @team - What is reason for loop? Because always loops are avoid in pandas, because slow.

Comment: Here I add the reason behind of the timedelta writing in for loop. "For the reference to jezrael: "  please look at my question last part.

Comment: @team - hmmm, I think not necessary loop, edited answer.

Comment: hmm what you suggested code is correct as far. But this is not giving my required answer and the graph is not correct also. :-(

Comment: Can you suggest me any code how to write in  for loop that timedelta. I am really stuck with this. If you can help me it will be a great chances to carry on my other code

Comment: @team - Ok, so what is expcted output of `new1` ? What is expcted output of your loop `x` ?

Comment: @ jezrael But here values are displaying according to the datetime so then what I expected graph Is not displaying properly. expected output of my loop x I wrote in my question in my last part. please look at that desired output for x. I hope you will understand it . Edit the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199557/discussion-between-jezrael-and-team).

Comment: @ jezrael I wrote the new question. I hope now you will understand what I am trying to ask " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971667/how-to-add-this-summation-equation-inside-of-the-for-loop-function" link of my new question